# Vendor.min.js in angular not working after page change

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm importing a html/css template into angular5 cli and am having issues with the **vendor.min.js.**

It's loading the **first time** for the single page app, but as soon **as I navigate to another page** it stops working.

I have to do a **hard refresh** to make it work again.

I've [installed jquery](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/11/18/3821/jquery-angular2-angularcli-how-to) using npm and included it into my **angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [
  "assets/js/vendor.min.js",
. . .
]
```

Comment: The issue is probably the fact that your jQuery `document.ready` handler only fires once, which is notmal since angular apps are SPAs.

Comment: If I add a jquery popup window it works on all pages without a hard refresh so I'm guessing jquery is working, but the vendor js is the issue.